# How to create a stored procedure in snowflake using insert into statement?

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have an insert into statement that look like this:

This query inserts into the table DB.PUBLIC.SK_HISTORY from a CTE created from 2 other tables. Then the CTE is pivoted before inserting it into DB.PUBLIC.SK_HISTORY.

```
INSERT INTO DB.PUBLIC.SK_HISTORY

WITH 

OPEN_PO AS 
(
    SELECT A.COL1, COL2, COL3, COL4, COL5, COL6, COL7, B.TIMING,

    SUM(COL8) AS OPEN_DOLLARS,
    COUNT(COL9) AS OPEN_LINES

    FROM  TBL_A A
    LEFT JOIN TBL_B B
    ON A.COL1= B.COL1
    GROUP BY 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8
)

SELECT *

FROM
(
    SELECT COL1, COL2, COL3, COL4, COL5, COL6, COL7, OPEN_LINES
    FROM OPEN_PO
) T

PIVOT
(
    SUM(OPEN_DOLLARS)
    FOR TIMING IN ('T1', 'T2', 'T3', 'T4')
) P
```

How do I create a stored procedure from this query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to this issue.
It's important to note that `EXCUTE AS CALLER` is required to prevent permission issues when calling the procedure.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE DB_NAME.SCHEMA.PROCEDURE_NAME()
RETURNS VARCHAR
LANGUAGE SQL
EXECUTE AS CALLER
AS
$$
DECLARE message VARCHAR;

BEGIN

INSERT INTO DB.PUBLIC.SK_HISTORY

WITH 

OPEN_PO AS 
(
    SELECT A.COL1, COL2, COL3, COL4, COL5, COL6, COL7, B.TIMING,

    SUM(COL8) AS OPEN_DOLLARS,
    COUNT(COL9) AS OPEN_LINES

    FROM  TBL_A A
    LEFT JOIN TBL_B B
    ON A.COL1= B.COL1
    GROUP BY 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8
)

SELECT *

FROM
(
    SELECT COL1, COL2, COL3, COL4, COL5, COL6, COL7, OPEN_LINES
    FROM OPEN_PO
) T

PIVOT
(
    SUM(OPEN_DOLLARS)
    FOR TIMING IN ('T1', 'T2', 'T3', 'T4')
) P
;

message := 'table updated successfully';
RETURN message;
END;
$$
```